# don't add to value if condition hasn't been met for a time limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, raspberry-pi, pwm

I'm controlling the forwards speed of a robot based on pwm (speed is determined the same way servos are controlled 1.5ms being neutral, 2ms, and 1ms being forwards and backwards respectively)

I want add 100µs to pwm if not key.get_pressed()[K_w] has lasted more than 0.5s (add 100µs to pwm once w is pressed if w was unpressed for less than 0.5 seconds)

details:
varible pwm is in units of µs, key.get_pressed()[K_w] returns the state of all keys (1 being pressed & 0 being not pressed)

bit of pseudocode:

```
while True:
  if key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
    pwm = pwm + 100 if w's time since last pressed has lasted < 0.5 seconds
    throttle(pwm)
```

I'm utterly sick of dealing with this I've been stuck on it for a week and I hate it.

Comment: So if the 'w' key is pressed, then pressed again within half a second you want to increase your pwm variable by 100?

Comment: yes that is the goal

Comment: Glad you got that btw was worried nobody would understand

Comment: NP. It took a few reads through to determine exactly what you were after, but the information was all there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work (haven't tested)

```
import time
last_press = 0
if key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
  span = time.time() - last_press
  last_press = time.time()
  if span < 0.5:
    pwm += 100
    throttle(pwm)
```

Comment: Want to join my GitHub repository?

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.

Comment: did this solution fail?

Comment: It provided me with the means of creating my own

Comment: Cool. I'll check out your solution in github.

Comment: its still being written